# GitHub Container Actions in Containerised Runner

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, github-actions, docker-in-docker

I have deployed a pool of self hosted GitHub runners as pods to my kubernetes cluster. Some of our pipelines contain jobs which run container actions. Is it possible to run those jobs in this type of runner?

Docker in Docker is configured in the deployment, and I can build docker images and push them to the container registry.

I note that the GitHub docs state:

```
If you want to run workflows that use Docker container actions or service containers, you must use a Linux machine and Docker must be installed.
```

I've struggled to find any definitive answers to this online

Comment: I'm not sure you'll ever get a definitive answer on this as running Docker in Docker on Kubernetes is not really recommended these days, but from what I've seen, this should work.

Comment: Are you using GKE or Kubernetes?

If, you're using GKE... Does your node pool use [COS images](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/node-images?hl=en#cos)?  
  
if yes, what COS version are you using?